# CRM RetrieveMultipleResponse not returning any results

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm

I am attempting to make a console application to retrieve results using the Dynamics CRM SDK and C# but I can't seem to get any results from my queries. I am able to see that I am connected to the server, but any QueryExpression I try to make seems to come back with nothing, even if I set it with no filter. Even when using an example from the documentation that we have corresponding values to I end up empty handed. My code is:

```
        CrmServiceClient crmSvc = new CrmServiceClient(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyCRMServer"].ConnectionString);
        Console.WriteLine(crmSvc.IsReady);
        //Display the CRM version number and org name that you are connected to.
        Console.WriteLine("Connected to CRM! (Version: {0}; Org: {1}",
        crmSvc.ConnectedOrgVersion, crmSvc.ConnectedOrgUniqueName);

        QueryExpression userSettingsQuery = new QueryExpression("contact");
        userSettingsQuery.ColumnSet.AllColumns = true;
        var retrieveRequest = new RetrieveMultipleRequest()
        {
            Query = userSettingsQuery
        };
        EntityCollection EntCol = (crmSvc.ExecuteCrmOrganizationRequest(retrieveRequest) as RetrieveMultipleResponse).EntityCollection;
        foreach (var a in EntCol.Entities)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Account name: {0} {1}", a.Attributes["firstname"], a.Attributes["lastname"]);
        }
        Console.Write(crmSvc.LastCrmError);
        Console.Write(crmSvc.LastCrmException);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

It returns no errors, and shows True for the connection, and I can't seem to find where to start to troubleshoot from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine for me so it may be that the user you are connected as doesn't have permission to read `contact` records or there are no `contact` records in your CRM organization.

Also, I know you are trying to piece together a sample, but I put together a more straight forward version of your code below.

```
    var crmSvc = new CrmServiceClient(<CONNECTION STRING>);

    var contactQuery = new QueryExpression("contact")
    {
        ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("firstname", "lastname")
    };
    var contacts = crmSvc.RetrieveMultiple(contactQuery).Entities;
    foreach(var contact in contacts)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Contact name: {0} {1}", contact.GetAttributeValue<String>("firstname"), contact.GetAttributeValue<String>("lastname"));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the improved code, this is kinda some pieced together code that I got after messing with it a lot of different ways to try to get it to work. I'll have to talk to my CRM department as I have had permission issues in the past. Thanks.